# Paho subscriber on_message does not print out the received message

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am using mosquitto as broker which works properly, the publisher does as well. Unfortunately the on_message function does not print out the received data and I have absolutey no idea why.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 
import psycopg2 as psy
import numpy as np

mqtt_hostname = "192.168.15.26" #IP adress of broker
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
mqtt_topic = "testmabi"
mqtt_port = "1883"
mqtt_port = int(mqtt_port)

Keep_Alive_Interval = 120 
granted_qos = 2

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(mqtt_topic)
    print("on_subscribe succeeded")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("MQTT Data Received...")
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))   
    Data_Handler(msg.topic, msg.payload)

def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos): 
    pass

mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# Assign event callbacks
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
print("on_connect succeeded")
mqttc.on_message = on_message
print("on_message succeeded")

mqttc.connect(mqtt_hostname, int(mqtt_port), int(Keep_Alive_Interval))

# Continue the network loop
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

**my output:**

```
on_connect succeeded
on_message succeeded
Connected with result code 0
on_subscribe succeeded
```

Comment: How are you sure that your client is receiving the message? How do you send the message to the subscribed channel?

Comment: That code works just fine. As @MarteValerioFalcone asked, how are you publishing test messages? Also since you are subscribing at QOS 0  and with Clean Session set to true no queued messages will be delivered.

Comment: My publisher is a Sinumerik control system of a robot. Using MQTTLens as a test client a received all messages. I also tried it qit qos 1 and 2, but it does not make any difference.

Comment: Please share an example message as received in MQTTLens (ensure you include the topic).

Comment: It seems the art of debugging has been lost. 2 line changes to the above to set broker to test.mosquitto.org and topic to # shows the code at least consuming messages. So, the likely user error is that nothing gets published to the OP topic on the broker.

Comment: Ok, Thank you! There are definitely messages published to the topic. I tested that. Maybe it`s a network problem as publisher and client are in different networks and I am using port forwarding to solve that issue. Maybe that's the problem...